# RAML2HTML Templates Library

Tags: templates, raml, api-doc

We recently decided to use [RAML](http://raml.org/) to document our API and all seems great so far.

We are using the [raml2html](https://github.com/raml2html/raml2html) utility to generate static HTML documentation. The default template works great, but I've seen much better API pages. Does anyone know about some collection of examples/ready-to-use templates?

EDIT: As RAML is evolving, the tools around it are evolving as well. I recently found a very nice theme that might be of interest: https://github.com/wdullaer/raml2html-slate-theme

Comment: Were you able to find good templates / good libraries of templates

Comment: No, not yet :(. We decided to write our own. You can check it out here - https://gitlab.com/officernd/officernd.gitlab.io and how it looks like here - http://developer.officernd.com

Comment: Omg thanks so much! : )
I love it!

Comment: That looks very nice! Why don't you consider sending this to raml2html as a pull request? We're definitely in need of a better default template and more contributors.

Comment: A huge improvement on the default raml2html template, which I'd say has questionable usability with its modal window approach. I tried the [slate theme](https://github.com/wdullaer/raml2html-slate-theme) which has potential but it's missing some major features - like RAML 1.0 data types